# python long number data loss

Tags: python, python-3.x, biginteger, data-loss

i am just starting with python (python3) because i read its good for the euler project since it can handle very big numbers.

now i am struggling with a quite simple problem of converting float to int. Why don't i get the same result for this:

```
num =  6008514751432349174082765599289028910605977570

print('num     {0} '.format(int(num)))

num = num / 2
print('num /2  {0} '.format(int(num)))

num = num * 2
print('num *2  {0} '.format(int(num)))
```

output for this is:

```
num     6008514751432349174082765599289028910605977570 
num /2  3004257375716174771611310192874715313222975488 
num *2  6008514751432349543222620385749430626445950976
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using float division, which cannot handle large numbers with as much precision, after which you are flooring the result by casting it back to an `int()`.

Don't do that, that causes data loss. Use [integer (floor) division with `//`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) instead:

```
>>> 6008514751432349174082765599289028910605977570 // 2 * 2
6008514751432349174082765599289028910605977570
```

This still can lead to rounding errors of course, if the input value is not divisible by 2 without flooring:

```
>>> 6008514751432349174082765599289028910605977571 // 2 * 2
6008514751432349174082765599289028910605977570
```

but floating point values are limited in precision based on your exact CPU support; see [`sys.float_info`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) to see what exact limitations your platform imposes on float numbers.

On my Mac, `sys.float_info.dig` tells me my platform supports 15 digits of precision, but you are dividing a 46-digit integer number. This means that you throw away the bottom *30* digits from your large integer when using float division:

```
>>> len(str(int(6008514751432349174082765599289028910605977570 / 2) - (6008514751432349174082765599289028910605977570 // 2)))
30
```

That is a *lot* of precision loss there. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters when does someone use `//` instead of `/`?

Comment: @dustin: when you want to apply integer division (so the result being an `int`) instead of a floating point value.

Comment: @dustin: When you are working with integer values with more digits than the number of digits your platform can support (see `sys.float_info.dig`) then you'll see precision loss when you use float division.